# EXCEL database query ODBC Error post migrating to a new machine

Tags: excel, odbc

I have a workbook with a database query and moving it to a new machine I get the following error:

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

This is the Connection I have used on about a half dozen computers on the network.

[image]

The version of Excel is the same, and every driver I have on the old machine is there:

Sql native client 11

Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server

But I still get the error on this new machine, any help would be great, I have read half of the internet at this point and it all seems to say it's a named connection issue even though they don't exist on any of the machines it works on.

note: I can connect to the server on the new machine but the connection type is oleDB, not Database query. I did recreate the workbook using that method but it was unsharable every person even admins had to rebuild the connection string, so I'm hoping I can fix what I got.

Answer (score 0):

after lots more searching it turns out that the database query in Excel is deprecated, but still supported if you install the .NET framework version 4.6 or higher.  I installed 4.7 on the new machine rebooted and the excel connection works.

Comment: looks like it also needed native client 12.  wouldn't work with 11 for some reason.